# Find a specific value in a CSV file using PHP

Tags: php, csv

i have csv file available and i want to find value 
Ex:

> sku          qty
>
> 11111         2 
>  22222         4 
>  333333        6

then i want to qty of `22222` sku

how can i will achieve it ?

my code is like below way ...

```
$handle = fopen("test.csv", "r");
        //rewind($handle);
        $count = 0;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== false) {

            $count++;
            if ($count == 1) {
                continue;
            }
            for ($i = 0, $j = count($data); $i < $j; $i++) {
                $insert_csv = array();
                $insert_csv['sku'] = $data[0];
                $insert_csv['qty'] = !empty($data[1]) ? $data[1] : 0;

            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
```

and my csv file output like this way ...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = file("test.csv");

for ($i = 2, $size = sizeof($file); $i < $size; $i++) {
    $line = explode(';', $file[$i]);
    if (trim($line[0]) === '22222') {
        $answer = trim($line[1]);
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay i have added image my output of csv now how can achieve that